# ebean unidirectional @OneToOne relation with unique constraint

Tags: jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a User class:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

@Id
public Long id;
public String email;
public String name;
public String password;
}
```

and a driver class

```
@Entity
public class Driver extends Model {
@Id
public Long id;

@OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Column(unique = true)
public User user;
}
```

I want to make sure that the user_id is unique inside the Drivers table. But the code above does not enforce that. (I can create multiple drivers with the same user id).

Ideally, I do not want to add the @OneToOne relations in the User class because there are several different roles inside my app (e.g. driver, teacher, agent etc.) and I don't want to pollute user class with all those relations.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried this code on the model for me, and it worked. One thing to be noted, that you must use `@OneToOne` annotation to let the ORM knows that you have foreign key reference to other model.

The model look like following:

```
@Entity
// add unique constraint to user_id column
@Table(name = "driver", 
       uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "user_id")
)
public class Driver extends Model {
   @Id
   public Long id;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   public User user;
}
```

It will generate evolution script like this :

```
create table driver (
   id            bigint not null,
   user_id       bigint,

   constraint uq_driver_1 unique (user_id), # unique database constraint
   constraint pk_driver primary key (id)
);
```

So, with this method you can make sure that you will have unique `user` reference on `driver` table.

---

> #### Additional Info
>
> Because there is an additional constraint, that is not handled by framework but by the database applied on the model (*such as the* `unique` *constraint*), to validate the input or handling the occurred exception, you can surround `Model.save()` or `form.get().save()` expression (*saving-the-model*) with `try-catch` block to handle the **PersistenceException**.